# Changing a Attribute value in a Manifest after copying it from another Manifest in ANT script

Tags: java, ant

I have a manifest file located at "..plugins/xyz.abc.e.tool.sa.app/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"

I want to copy the Build-version: 3.15.0.vqualifier and put it in my new Manifest File in another location as Build-version: 3.15.0. Can someone help me with the changes I need to make in my ANT Script?

```
<target name="create_sacode_jar">       
    <loadproperties srcFile="${buildDirectory}/plugins/xyz.abc.e.tool.sa.rcp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
        <filterchain>
            <linecontains>
                <contains value="Bundle-Version" />
            </linecontains>
        </filterchain>
    </loadproperties>
    <jar destfile="${buildDirectory}/../bin/SACode.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
            <attribute name="Bundle-Version" value="${Bundle-Version}" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins/xyz.abc.e.tool.sa.Generator/@dot" />
        <fileset dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins/xyz.abc.e.tool.sa.SAcode/@dot" />
    </jar>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jar manifest is not a properties file.  They look similar, but they don’t use the same format.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) is the format of a properties file.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#jar-manifest) is the format of a jar manifest.

Among the differences are:

- Manifest lines have length limitations.
- Manifests do not, as far as I know, permit escape sequences.
- In a manifest, attribute names only need to be unique with a section.
- Continuation lines are different.

As far as I know, there is no standard Ant task that will read individual manifest entries.  However, you can “cheat” and use a [script](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html):

```
<script language="javascript">
    var Manifest = Java.type("java.util.jar.Manifest");
    var Files = Java.type("java.nio.file.Files");
    var Paths = Java.type("java.nio.file.Paths");
    var BufferedInputStream = Java.type("java.io.BufferedInputStream");

    var path = Paths.get(
        project.getProperty("buildDirectory"),
        "plugins/xyz.abc.e.tool.sa.rcp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");

    var stream = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(path));
    var manifest = new Manifest(stream);
    stream.close();

    var version = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Bundle-Version");
    project.setProperty("Bundle-Version", version);
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured this "cheat" to get over this problem. I couldn't find any other way. Thank you so much anyway! :)